# Remove or overwrite style-l.css in custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, theme, template, css

I have some issues because of the order that CSS is being loaded in. We have

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://<site>/pub/static/_cache/merged/c53078aed3784c1f81c0316580b47a29.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="https://<site>/pub/static/frontend/Thespicery/standard/en_GB/css/styles-l.css" />
```

I really need the cached file to be loaded after the **style-l.css**.

I am relatively happy to remove the style-l.css altogether but as yet have failed.

I have tried:

- Removing the parent them (current Magento Blank) from the XML but this doesn't actually remove the reference to the file - it only deletes the actual file and then gives a 404 error (which technically works but I don't want the `<link>` in the source code
- In `default_head_blocks.xml` for Magento Theme overrides adding:

`<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/style-l.css</name></action>`

and

`<action method="removeItem"><css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/></action>`

but to no avail.

***What is the correct way of doing this? Should I just try to change the load order (is that even possible), or should I remove style-l.css (and if so, how?)?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To remove CSS via XML:**

In your theme add the following XML to `default.xml`

```
<head>
    <remove src="css/styles-l.css" />
</head>
```

[Source](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

Your method didn't work because you're using the Magento 1 method of removing CSS. In Magento 2 `<action>` tags have been deprecated and `skin_css` is no longer used, in fact I don't think the theme is referenced to as skin at all anymore.

Comment: I have removed  styles-l.css from default.xml but it's still showing in page speed mobile mode what to do?

Comment: try adding this code to the default_head_blocks.xml file

Answer (score 0):

In `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`:

```xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Remove local styles resources -->
        <remove src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <remove src="<Namespace>_<ModuleName>::css/styles.css"/>

        <!-- Remove external resources -->
        <remove src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

[Source](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove).

> In some cases, you need to duplicate the code in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.